# Get argument value from TextTransform.exe into the template

Tags: t4, template-engine

I can't found some example how can I use argument -a when I use TextTransform.exe to generate code from templates. In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) is following description for argument -a:

> "Specifies a parameter that a directive
>   processor can query for as a
>   name/value pair. The directive
>   processor and identifier are optional.
>   This allows parameters to be specified
>   for any directive processor or any
>   instance of a particular directive
>   processor."

I need some set of arguments like connection string and so on in my template. My idea was to get a path to configuration file with help of argument -a.

Regards
Anton Kalcik

UPDATE: To be clear enough, I want read parameters direct in template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Text Template Transformation Toolkit(T4) is from Microsoft not very well supported. Only few examples. If you want to know more go to [Olegs Sychs blog](http://www.olegsych.com/). T4 is here very deeply explained.

After of hours to trying to get parameters from TextTransform.exe in my template I found a solution:

Add `hostspecific="true"` attribute to `template` element as follows:

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="true"#>
```

Later in template you can call `ResolveParameterValue` as Oleg mentioned.

Example:

```
<#

 string parameterTest = Host.ResolveParameterValue(null, null, "someKey");
 WriteLine(parameterTest);

#>
```

You call template generator so:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2\TextTransform.exe" -a !!someKey!someValue
```

After generating should be in generated file: 'someValue'

Comment: With VS2010, passing nulls or empty string to either of the first 2 parameters of `Host.ResolveParameterValue(null, null, "someKey")` causes an argument null exception.

Comment: The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) also explains the same solution.

Comment: How to pass the multiple numbers of arguments?

Comment: @CodingWithSpike: How to overcome the argument null exception.

Comment: Just add a try/catch:  `try { Host.ResolveParameterValue(.....)  } catch(Exception) { }`

Answer (score 1):

The -a argument accepts values in the following format:

```
<ProcessorName>!<DirectiveID>!<ParameterName>
```

These are also the parameters of [ITextTemplatingEngineHost.ResolveParameterValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.itexttemplatingenginehost.resolveparametervalue.aspx) method which you need to call in order to get parameter value in template code.

Comment: Hello Oleg, thank you for response. Do you mean I can call ResolveParameterValue in my *.tt file? What should be set for parameter directiveId and processorName? Could you provide some example? Regards Anton Kalcik

Comment: @OlegSych: What will be the value for directiveId

Comment: @OlegSych: What will be the value for directiveId