# T4 default template parameters

Tags: templates, t4, visual-studio-extensions, scaffolding

I want to pass in the default template parameters of a context controller T4 template from the CodeGenerator function for a new extension as such:

```
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerRootName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Namespace" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="AreaName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ContextTypeName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ModelTypeName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ModelVariable" #>
<#@ parameter type="Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Core.Metadata.ModelMetadata" name="ModelMetadata" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="EntitySetVariable" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.Boolean" name="UseAsync" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.Boolean" name="IsOverpostingProtectionRequired" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="BindAttributeIncludeText" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name ="OverpostingWarningMessage" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.String>" name="RequiredNamespaces" #>
```

These are passed in through the scaffolding process from the Microsoft's MVC dll automatically but since I am overriding the scaffolding process with my own I want to pass them in myself in here:

```
public override void GenerateCode()
    {
        // Get the selected code type
        var codeType = _viewModel.SelectedModelType.CodeType;

        // Add the custom scaffolding item from T4 template.
        this.AddFileFromTemplate(Context.ActiveProject,
            "MVCBootstrapServerTable",
            "CustomTextTemplate",
            GetParameters(),           //to provide the parameters here!
            skipIfExists: false);
    }
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected virtual IDictionary<string, object> AddTemplateParameters(CodeType dbContextType, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
{
  if (dbContextType == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (dbContextType));
  if (modelMetadata == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (modelMetadata));
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Model.ControllerName))
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.Properties.Resources.InvalidControllerName);
  IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>) new Dictionary<string, object>((IEqualityComparer<string>) StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  CodeType codeType = this.Model.ModelType.CodeType;
  dictionary.Add("ModelMetadata", (object) modelMetadata);
  string str = codeType.Namespace != null ? codeType.Namespace.FullName : string.Empty;
  dictionary.Add("ModelTypeNamespace", (object) str);
  HashSet<string> requiredNamespaces = this.GetRequiredNamespaces((IEnumerable<CodeType>) new List<CodeType>()
  {
    codeType,
    dbContextType
  });
  dictionary.Add("RequiredNamespaces", (object) requiredNamespaces);
  dictionary.Add("ModelTypeName", (object) codeType.Name);
  dictionary.Add("ContextTypeName", (object) dbContextType.Name);
  dictionary.Add("UseAsync", (object) this.Model.IsAsyncSelected);
  string escapedIdentifier = ValidationUtil.GenerateCodeDomProvider(this.Model.ActiveProject.GetCodeLanguage()).CreateEscapedIdentifier(this.Model.ModelType.ShortTypeName.ToLowerInvariantFirstChar());
  dictionary.Add("ModelVariable", (object) escapedIdentifier);
  dictionary.Add("EntitySetVariable", (object) modelMetadata.EntitySetName.ToLowerInvariantFirstChar());
  if (this.Model.IsViewGenerationSupported)
  {
    bool flag = OverpostingProtection.IsOverpostingProtectionRequired(codeType);
    dictionary.Add("IsOverpostingProtectionRequired", (object) flag);
    if (flag)
    {
      dictionary.Add("OverpostingWarningMessage", (object) OverpostingProtection.WarningMessage);
      dictionary.Add("BindAttributeIncludeText", (object) OverpostingProtection.GetBindAttributeIncludeText(modelMetadata));
    }
  }
  return dictionary;
}
```

I have since got much more deeper into the logic by calling the required classes for the values above to populate with the right values according to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can process a template by using the text templating service. Sample code, please refer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586944.aspx#Anchor_1

If you want to get the parameters from T4 template, you need to use [ITextTemplatingEngineHost.ResolveParameterValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.itexttemplatingenginehost.resolveparametervalue.aspx) Method. Before use this method, you also need to Add hostspecific="true" attribute to template element.

Sample code, you code refer to:

[Get argument value from TextTransform.exe into the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221651/get-argument-value-from-texttransform-exe-into-the-template)

Comment: Thanks Wendy, however what I want is to populate the ControllerName string, ControllerRootName, Namespace, AreaName, ContextTypeName, ModelTypeName.... etc with their respective values.

Comment: In the sample code, it use ITextTemplatingSessionHost.CreateSession() method, which could pass value with key-value pairs. You could set the key name as ControllerName, ControllerRootName...etc and set the respective values for them.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining myself well. I know how to pass the values. All I want is to GET the values for ControllerName, ControllerRootName etc (entire list of parameters in my original post).

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your questions. I have edit my answer. Please check whether it is helpful. If any questions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Wendy, thanks for the answer. I upvoted your answer however it won't show for now as I do not have 15 reputations points. I did not mark it as the most helpful answer because I in the meantime I found a better answer myself. I will post below for you and other to see too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are waiting for your better answer and thanks for sharing your answer. Please remember to mark your answer after sharing.